# Неожиданный символ, встречающийся при разборе значения

Tags: c#, json, файлы, asp.net-mvc

записываю данные в файл

```
private List<Book> GetBook()
    {
        string serializedJSONString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Users/Anuitex-55/source/repos/Library.WEB/Library.WEB/Book.json");
        var deserializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Book>>(serializedJSONString);
        return deserializedResult;
    }
```

Так моя программа работает ,но указывать полный путь не комильфо ,поэтому начал искать как сделать без ввода полного пути и пришел к такому

```
private List<Book> GetBook()
    {
        string serializedJSONString = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Book.json");
        var deserializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Book>>(serializedJSONString);
        return deserializedResult;
    }
```

но теперь мне выдаёт следующую ошибку

```
[JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path '', line 0, position 0.]
```

Кто знает как решить мою проблему ?

Пробовал

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("~/Book.json");
```

но из-за этого появляется ошибка здесь

```
var deserializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Book>>(sr);
```

говорит что нельзя преобразовать System.IO.StreamReader в string

Кто может помочь ? Если мало инфы пишите я дополню

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прочитать же надо содержимое файла:

```
string serializedJSONString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(
    System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Book.json")
);
```

Comment: спасибо огромное